# Remove blank paragraph tags - TinyMCE

Tags: c#, regex, string, tinymce, strip-tags

I am trying to remove blank paragraphs generated by TinyMCE.  I want to use a RegEx because the set of HTML tags is finite in my universe but I am not sure how to go about it.

For this purpose my definition of blank is anything that does not have text.  Here are some blank tag paragraphs I am getting from TinyMCE:

```
<p><strong><br></strong></p>
<p><br></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p></p>
```

Basically if no text is going to show up inside the paragraph tags, I want to remove it.. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) a try, it'll parse your HTML fragment into a DOM which can be traversed to strip any `<p>` tags that meet your criteria.  This'll be much easier and more robust that using a regex.